# $ is not Function (Error Occurring in JQuery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm doing a laravel project with front-end in html/css/bootstrap.

I'm using Jquery 1.12.4 version

```
        (function($) {
            "use strict";
    
    function handlePreloader() {
            if($('.preloader').length){
                $('.preloader').delay(200).fadeOut(500);
            }
        }
            
        function headerStyle() {
                if($('.main-header').length){
                    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
                    var siteHeader = $('.main-header');
                    var scrollLink = $('.scroll-to-top');
                    if (windowpos >= 200) {
                        siteHeader.addClass('fixed-header');
                        scrollLink.fadeIn(300);
                    } else {
                        siteHeader.removeClass('fixed-header');
                        scrollLink.fadeOut(300);
                    } 
        }
            }
            
            headerStyle();
        
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                headerStyle();
            });
            $(window).on('load', function() {
                handlePreloader();
            }); 
        
        })(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this before loading jQuery.js? Inspect what `$` is inside your IIFE

Comment: No First JQuery and then Script file

Comment: So what did you see when inspect `$`?

Comment: I have also added lazy loading  function handlePreloader() {
  if($('.preloader').length){
   $('.preloader').delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  }
 }

Comment: please see the latest edit

Comment: OK...for the third time, what is `$` inside code when when logged to console? We can't help if you don't answer debugging detail questions or provide a [mcve] that demonstrates problem

Answer (score 1):

to use $ symbol You must have made jQuery available to your script.

use below CDN it will import all jquery related things in the page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`

Comment: JQuery is available in project folder at the right place and some of the other functions of Jquery are smoothly running.

Comment: what version of jquery you're using can you show us

Comment: I'm using Jquery 1.12.4 version

Comment: that is a too old one, change your jquery to a new one

Comment: I try to add JQuery  CDN that you provide above but nothing work 
I'm getting the same error ..